# MongoDb combine selection with $or and $limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using mongoose with a MongoDb. The test runs are saved with the current state they are in. I would like to get the open or running test runs and the last ten finished test runs.

How can this be achieved?

The query i have for now looks like this:

```js
...

models.testRun.find()
  .or([
    { isOpen: true },
    { isRunning: true },
    { $and: [{ isOpen: false }] } // missing statement to select 10 entries
  ])
  .sort({
    updatedAt: "descending"
  })
  .populate(populateQuery)
  .exec((error, testRuns) => {
    console.log(testRuns);
  });
```

At the last $or entry i thought i can enter a $and query which selects the last ten test runs.

The schema of a test run looks like this

```js
const testRunSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   isOpen: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
   },
   isRunning: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
   },
   hasError: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
   },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
...

models.testRun.find()
  .or([
    { isOpen: true },
    { isRunning: true },
    { $and: [{ isOpen: false }] } // missing statement to select 10 entries
  ])
  .sort({
    updatedAt: "descending"
  }
  .{ $limit : 10 })
  .populate(populateQuery)
  .exec((error, testRuns) => {
    console.log(testRuns);
  });
```

The above addition should work, unless something specific about Mongoose

Comment: Yes this works if you want to limit all values that are queried. But i would like to get the open, running and the last 10 finished runs

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can either $aggregate or you can literally run 3 queries to cursor -- { isOpen: true }, --> { $limit : 10 }, { isRunning: true } ---> { $limit : 10 } etc. then combine the cursors by way of merging the Json and send the final result to whereever you need to.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. The open and running tests don't need to be limited. Could you update your answer?